# Unicorn workers' first responses are slower by few seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn

I can't figure out how I can get my unicorn workers to only accept connections when they're really "ready" to process a request. I find that the first few requests are slow, then they speed up dramatically (from a few seconds down to a hundred or so ms). This problem seems to be compounded by the fact that unicorn seems to kill workers after a certain amount of time, meaning that I'm constantly facing the performance hit of the slow first request. Has anyone else seen this or have an idea of what I can do?

Comment: Please check this https://github.com/ooyala/barkeep/issues/237 may be it will help you.

Comment: Are you [preloading your app](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html#preload_app-method)?

Comment: because first request is not cached yet, and if u send the request again, you will use the cached query from first request.
if you want to improve your unicorn performance, Please check this http://blog.railsonfire.com/2012/05/06/Unicorn-on-Heroku.html

Comment: I do have `preload_app(true)`, and even if I wait for all the workers to spawn up and wait 5 minutes, the first request takes an extra few seconds (for each worker) -- e.g. if I have 16 workers, the first 16 or so requests (obviously the master does not route the requests evenly) take an extra few seconds, and after that requests take sub 100ms. I'm wondering what is not being "preloaded" in the workers... Or at least I am trying to figure out a way to get to the bottom of this. Could it be that the Workers are taking longer on the first request to establish connections to Redis and Sphinx?

Comment: Some things to check: Are all the usual production config settings controlling class caching and eager loading properly set?  Do you have code outside of the app directory which doesn't get eager loaded by default?

Comment: It's possible the Redis and Sphinx connection initialization takes some extra latency on first request.  You should probably establish those connections in unicorn's [`after_fork`](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html#after_fork-method) hook.

Comment: @dbenhur is there a good way for me to trace the time spent in different parts of the request in my production set up? Should I just put logger statements all over the place?

Comment: well, log statements will do the trick.  You might try using a profiler such as [perftools.rb](https://github.com/tmm1/perftools.rb) and compare the profile for the first and second request to a single worker. This [rack middleware](https://github.com/bhb/rack-perftools_profiler) makes it pretty simple to profile a single request.

Comment: @dbenhur ah, it's looking like it's the first time `I18n.t()` is called and all the yaml files have to get read into memory... Going to dig a bit deeper and see if I can load them after_fork so that the first request doesn't get hit. Will report back with more...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out the our i18n yml files being lazily loaded in the views on the first request was causing the performance issues. Simply adding the following to my config/unicorn.rb seems to have solved the issue:

```
before_fork do |server, worker|
  # The following is highly recomended for Rails + "preload_app true" as
  # there's no need for the master process to hold a connection.
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!

  # No need to disconnect from Redis servers--they are connected to lazily.

  # Force translations to be loaded into memory.
  I18n.t('activerecord')
end
```

Comment: Might be better code organization to do the `I18n.t('activerecord')` in a rails initializer instead of hidden in the before_fork hook.  initializers get run pre-fork when unicorn does the app preload.

Comment: Thank you! I never would have found that out I guess. It seems that this doesn't work in an initializer for me though.

Comment: @2called-chaos so it only works for you in the `before_fork` block?

Comment: @AaronGibralter I've actually put it into the after_fork block which seems to basically works, too. I still have a delay on the first request but only once for the instance not as before for each worker. Need to investigate further and on a faster machine (tested it on a rather slow VPS) :-) Desired goal has to be an unnoticeable app reload.

Comment: I've found that it seems to work better in the `before_fork` block for some reason...